# What are the orthogonal trajectories of the given family of curves: $(x-a)^2 + y^2 = a^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What are the orthogonal trajectories of the given family of curves: $(x-a)^2 + y^2 = a^2$

Take the derivative:

$$2(x-a)+ 2yy' = 0$$
$$x-a+ yy' = 0$$

$a$ can be isolated from the original equation $x^2-2ax+a^2+y^2=a^2 \rightarrow x^2-2ax+y^2=0$
Yielding the following differential equation:

$$x-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2x}+yy'=0$$

This is suppose to be a separable differential equation yielding $x^2+(y-C)^2 = C^2$. I can't seem to come this conclusion. Could someone help?

Comment: You've forgotten the most important step. Where are you remembering to look for *orthogonal* trajectories?

Comment: Your concluding equation is just another instance of the original equation where $x$ and $y$ switch roles and $C$ plays the role of $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your second equation due to orthogonality and complementary slopes

$$(x-a)+ yy'=0 ; \text { for orthogonal  trajectories replace }\;y'\to \frac {-1}{y'}$$

$$(x-a)= \frac{y}{y'}$$

Integrate. (steps are omitted).

$$ (y-b)^2 + x^2 = b^2 $$

where $b$ is an arbitrary constant.

The set of circles through origin touching y-axis have their O.Ts as a set of circles that touch x-axis.

BTW.. in polar coordinates they have a simple common differential equation
$$ \sin \psi = r/d \text{ where } \psi $$

is angle between radial/polar line and  tangent at pole or at the circle, $d$ is diameter of circle.

Answer (score 1):

Swiching $x$ and $y$ is correct.
Here is the original family: circles through the origin, center on the $x$ axis:
[image: S1]

Here is the orthogonal family: circles through the origin, center on the $y$ axis.
[image: S2]

Here they are superimposed, so we can see that they are orthogonal families.
[image: S3]

Comment: Nice picture, but not an analytical solution. :)